# Nextjs accordion SEO

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to implement a custom accordion that is SEO friendly in Nextjs, however the component uses state, and I must use it as a client component.

The accordion uses state to toggle classes that use "visibility" style.

As far as I understand, client components are not included in the initial HTML, thus the content is not available for crawlers.

```
//FaqItem.tsx
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import DecalSvg from "../decalSvg/DecalSvg";
import styles from "./FaqItem.module.scss";

interface IProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  expanded?: boolean;
}

export default function FaqItem(props: IProps) {
  const { title, description, expanded } = props;
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(expanded);

  const handleToggleActive = () => {
    setIsActive((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.faqWrapper}>
      <dt>
        <button
          id="accordion-header-1"
          aria-controls="accordion-panel-1"
          aria-expanded={isActive}
          onClick={handleToggleActive}
          className={`${styles.faqButton} ${isActive ? styles.expanded : ""}`}
        >
          <span>
            {title}
            <span className="color-primary">.</span>
          </span>
          <div className={styles.svgWrapper}>
            <DecalSvg
              className={styles.svg}
              aria-hidden="true"
              width={32}
              height={32}
            />
          </div>
        </button>
      </dt>
      <dd
        className={`${styles.details} ${isActive ? styles.active : ""}`}
        id="accordion-panel-1"
        aria-labelledby="accordion-header-1"
        // hidden={!isActive}
      >
        <p>{description}</p>
      </dd>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I make the content of the faq item (title and description) SEO friendly (Visible to crawlers and when googling)?
Is there another approach to this issue?
Am I understanding this wrong?

using NextJs 13.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're using `"use client;"` Next.js will still server-side render those components on first load. So you will get the SEO benefits.

You can verify this by opening the inspector in your browser, then going to the network tab and reload the page. Look at the first `.html` and you will see the "server side version" of your site.

Comment: You are right! I can see it in the initial html. Also confirmed it by disabling javascript. The docs are a little bit conflicting about client components. Thank you~